# how to show points on a map within a specific radius

Tags: google-maps, google-app-engine, geolocation

I have been looking around with no clear direction on how to address this issue. I am looking at giving users the ability to show points of interest on a map based using a specific radius (eg. 5, 10, 25 miles)...

What is the best solution to:
1- determine user geolocation (eg. maxmind? google map?)
2- show points of interest (currently loaded in GAE datastore) on a map

Any guidance appreciated!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps API's geolocation, per https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/ , is in my (biased!-) opinion quite good, but of course it makes sense for you to also shop around for competitors (sorry, I'm not familiar with them, and StackOverflow discourages questions asking for recommendations among different libraries, suppliers, &c).

Whatever you use to get the user's geolocation, the best way to apply it in App Engine is via the Search API, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/ -- you store your "points of interests" coordinates as a `GeoPoint` property of a search "document", then simply search on the index for "documents" with that property within a certain distance (in meters, but it's not hard to translate from miles to meters:-) of the user's location.

Finally, of course, you can go back to the Google Maps API (or any competitor you may prefer) to show the user a map with your points of interest displayed on it (as markers, appropriate images, whatever).